# 14 months waiting for first review time to go elsewhere?

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper to a journal , it was accepted to go to peer review and it has stuck there despite chasing up at 3 months 6 months 9 ,10, 11, 12, 13, 14 month intervals. time to give and go to another journal?
The first excuse given by the editor is that the paper is unusual and they had trouble getting reviewers. Then the excuse was they were changing the publishing process. The paper crosses entomology and physics disciplines. I m still waiting for the first review.

Comment: That sounds like a *really* interesting paper!

Comment: What does "changing the publishing process" mean, or have to do with anything?  Do you have any indication when the referees got started with your paper?

Comment: They moved the administration & publication but not the editorial to a leading academic commercial company.

Comment: Sounds like an unprofessional journal to me, particularly the second excuse makes little sense to me.

Comment: Unless this is a well-known respectable journal, I would consider asking to retract the submission and submitting elsewhere.

Answer (score 11):

If you've been waiting for 14 months, and they are still not handling the paper, I think it's time for one last round of interaction.

- State that you consider 14 months to be an unacceptably long time to have no response to reviews.
- State that you intend to withdraw the paper and take it elsewhere unless they can give you a *firm* and *near* deadline (no more than approximately one more month) when you will receive a decision on your paper.

At this point, either they will make you a firm promise or they won't.  And if they make you a promise, either they'll fulfill it or they won't.  If they won't make a promise, or if they miss their promised response date by more than one week, withdraw the paper and send it elsewhere.