# No reviews after 7 months of paper submission

Tags: journals, paper-submission, ieee

I have submitted a paper to IEEE transactions on knowledge and data engineering (TKDE).
Until now, it has been 7 months and the status of my paper is still "Under Review".
It has stayed in the same status from the first day of the submission.
I have sent an email to the admin of the journal, and she replied to me that the paper was being processed. I have waited more than 1 month without any update.

Has anyone experienced the same situation? What should I do?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of people have experienced the same situation. See e.g.

[Submission review is taking too long](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/120623/submission-review-is-taking-too-long)

[I submitted a paper five months ago. Should I wait a little bit more for a response?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65111/i-submitted-a-paper-five-months-ago-should-i-wait-a-little-bit-more-for-a-respo)

[Elsevier Review Speed](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80035/elsevier-review-speed)

[14 months waiting for first review time to go elsewhere?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45322/14-months-waiting-for-first-review-time-to-go-elsewhere)

In general: ask the editor pointed questions about what's happening to your paper. They might not be able to tell you when the reviews will be available, but they should be able to say things like "we've invited 4 reviewers of which 2 have declined". Ask them for that information, and perhaps when the review due dates are as well. With this information you can make educated guesses about how much longer it'll take to review your paper. If there's no sign at all that the article is being reviewed, then consider withdrawing and submitting your manuscript elsewhere.

Comment: Probably it's the right thing to do, but I don't want to create any pressure. How long is typical for the review process, for IEEE trans in general and specific for TKDE?

Comment: @lenhhoxung it's not my field so I don't know what the typical review time is. I'd ask your advisor/colleagues/collaborators in the field. As for putting pressure on the journal: as long as you don't sound aggressive, the journal administrator is unlikely to mind. They receive lots of such enquiries from authors.

Comment: Now it has been 1 year and I sent an email to the editor. 
He didn't reply. What should I do?